# C# Generic type pattern matching with an if

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, blazor

I have this enum definition in a blazor server project:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   MyValue1 = 1,
   MyValue2 = 2,
   ...
}
```

I have this blazor component (.razor file):

```
@typeparam T

@switch (e1)
{
   case MyEnum e2:
     @* Doing some stuff with e2 which is MyEnum type *@
     ...
     break;
   ...
}

@code
{
   [Parameter]
   public MyEnum e1 { get; set; }
}
```

This code works fine but i am not happy of how it is written.

I want to replace the switch by an if statement but it does not work. I have a compilation error when i am trying to cast e1 to MyEnum type, even if i check T's type...

Any idea ?

Thanks

** EDIT **

There is what i've tried and the compilation error i get:

```
@if (e1 is MyEnum)
{
   MyEnum e2 = e1 as MyEnum;
   ...
}
```

And the error is:

> The operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type
> ('MyEnum' is a non-nullable value type)

Comment: Please share the code which contains the issue, including the exact error message.

Comment: Is the generic type `T` unbounded, or are there generic constraints? What are you using `T` with in your code? What is `e1`? Could you show the code you tried to do with an if statement that's causing an error?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have no generic contraints. I have edit my initial question with code and compilation error message

Comment: Is the problem *actually* Blazor-specific? Please try it in regular C# code - if you have the same problem there, the question would be much clearer without any Blazor syntax.

Comment: "I have a compilation error when i am trying to cast e1 to MyEnum type" - no, you have a problem when trying to use the `as` operator. That's not a cast. If you *actually* cast, I suspect it'll be fine: `MyEnum e2 = (MyEnum) e1;`. I'd personally use a pattern though: `if (e1 is MyEnum e2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use :

```
MyEnum e2 = e1;
```